# Amazon In App Purchase in Live App testing is not working

Tags: in-app-purchase, amazon-fire-tv

I am facing some issues in Amazon In App Purchase in Live App Testing. I am stuck at this since last 4-5 days, tried a lots of solutions but not able to move further. I am using Amazon in app purchase SDK. I have taken sample project that comes with Amazon SDK. I have changed my SKU in it, For local testing i am usign App Tester and app is working fine. Now I have uploaded app on Live App testing and created IAP item on Amazon account then App on Live app testing stop working.

Activity onResume code is below-

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sampleIapManager.activate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: call getUserData");
        PurchasingService.getUserData();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: getPurchaseUpdates");
        PurchasingService.getPurchaseUpdates(false);

        System.out.println(TAG + " onResume: call getProductData for skus: " + MySku.values());
        final Set<String> productSkus = new HashSet<String>();
        for (final MySku mySku : MySku.values()) {
            System.out.println("TAG , SKU information = "+mySku.getSku());
            productSkus.add(mySku.getSku());
        }
        PurchasingService.getProductData(productSkus);

    }
```

SKU json that defined on store -

```
{
  "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine.quarter": {
    "smallIconUrl": "https://com-amazon-mas-catalog.s3.amazonaws.com/amzn1.devportal.fileupload.6b3d68d2073e4bfb9f9d273448d51cc6_23d65d61-4fb7-44bd-b7c1-aeb6bc885981_09a3dbc2307fb170a718a981c150c1f1",
    "title": "Subscription Plan",
    "itemType": "SUBSCRIPTION",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "Subscription to My Magazine",
    "languageTitleMap": {
      "US": "Subscription Plan"
    },
    "languageDescriptionMap": {
      "US": "Subscription to My Magazine"
    },
    "currencyPriceMap": {
      "US": 0
    },
    "subscriptionParent": "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine"
  },
  "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine.month": {
    "smallIconUrl": "https://com-amazon-mas-catalog.s3.amazonaws.com/amzn1.devportal.fileupload.6b3d68d2073e4bfb9f9d273448d51cc6_23d65d61-4fb7-44bd-b7c1-aeb6bc885981_09a3dbc2307fb170a718a981c150c1f1",
    "title": "Subscription Plan",
    "itemType": "SUBSCRIPTION",
    "price": 5,
    "description": "Subscription to My Magazine",
    "languageTitleMap": {
      "US": "Subscription Plan"
    },
    "languageDescriptionMap": {
      "US": "Subscription to My Magazine"
    },
    "currencyPriceMap": {
      "US": 0
    },
    "subscriptionParent": "com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine"
  }
}
```

MySku.java in Code -

```
    package com.example.sampleiap;
/**
 * 
 * MySku enum contains all In App Purchase products definition that the sample
 * app will use. The product definition includes two properties: "SKU" and
 * "Available Marketplace".
 * 
 */
public enum MySku {

    //The only subscription product used in this sample app
    MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS("com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine", "US"),
    MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_MONTH("com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine.month", "US"),
    MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_QUARTER("com.amazon.sample.iap.subscription.mymagazine.quarter", "US");

    private final String sku;
    private final String availableMarkpetplace;

    /**
     * Returns the Sku string of the MySku object
     * @return
     */
    public String getSku() {
        return this.sku;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Available Marketplace of the MySku object
     * @return
     */
    public String getAvailableMarketplace() {
        return this.availableMarkpetplace;
    }

    private MySku(final String sku, final String availableMarkpetplace) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.availableMarkpetplace = availableMarkpetplace;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the MySku object from the specified Sku and marketplace value.
     * @param sku
     * @param marketplace
     * @return
     */
    public static MySku fromSku(final String sku, final String marketplace) {
       /* if (MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getSku().equals(sku) && (null == marketplace || MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getAvailableMarketplace()
                .equals(marketplace))) {
            return MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS;
        }*/

        return MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getSku().equals(sku) && (null == marketplace || MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS.getAvailableMarketplace()
                .equals(marketplace)) ? MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS :

                (MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_MONTH.getSku().equals(sku) && (marketplace == null || MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_MONTH.getAvailableMarketplace().equals(marketplace)))
                ? MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_MONTH : (MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_QUARTER.getSku().equals(sku) && (marketplace == null || MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_QUARTER.getAvailableMarketplace().equals(marketplace))) ? MY_MAGAZINE_SUBS_QUARTER : null;

    }

}
```

Build.gradle code -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sampleiapus"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.76.jar')
}
```

Proguard file -

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-optimizations !code/allocation/variable
```

If proguard file does not contain **-optimizations !code/allocation/variable**
then when i click on purchase button then it shows me an error dialog.

[image]

and if i am putting the line **-optimizations !code/allocation/variable** then i am not getting onPurchase event. Please help me in it. i am stuck since last 5 days in it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit the IAP items on Amazon developer console? Their status should be "LIVE", otherwise your app cannot retrieve them at runtime. I suspect that's what caused the error message.

If that's not the problem, checking logcat should help identify the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. IAP status is already LIVE on store but when i am calling PurchasingService.purchase(sku) then it gives me error. Please have a look to below logs .https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Fk6eZM9XnLFojlZMADhKcMSzGlNzQQuLW6T24-ywVMo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @nitintyagi Can you post the full log (starting from the time when you launch your app)? Check if there's any error during the IAP initialization. I would also recommend disabling Proguard for now to help isolate the issue. Have you tried calling getProductData()? You can use it to confirm the sku is available.

Comment: yes, I am calling getProductData() method and its confirms that SKU is available. I will put the whole log in some time.

Comment: @nitintyagi : hi i have the same issue, please let me know if you fix this issue

Comment: @mind Yes, i fixed it. You have to check couple of things at your side.  1. Check whether you created right sku on amazon portal and from app you are calling same. 2. Check progaurd file and keep required lines there. 3. check once by disabling proguard.